# Can I keep an AIR NativeProcess running after the AIR application itself exists?

Tags: air

My need is simple - I want to launch an external application from my AIR application, leaving the external application running while the AIR application itself exits.

The scenario is an "Install" button inside the application, that launches the 3rd party installer - the AIR application needs to close during this process.

My code to actually launch the NativeProcess object is fine, the process launches and can be used.  However, if the user closes the AIR application manually, or if I attempt to close the AIR application after launching the external process via ActionScript, the external application exists almost immediately.

Some example code:

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("My Great Application");
var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

// Either one of the two calls following will fail with the same result
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit()
this.nativeWindow.close();
```

I have also tried another approach to keep the external application open after the AIR application exists, using a proxy of sorts. On a Mac, I'm using the `/usr/bin/open` command. `/usr/bin/open` does open the external application and leave it running after the AIR application exists, however a Terminal window is on the screen with this approach, and that's not acceptable either.

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = new File("/usr/bin/open");
var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
args.push(file.nativePath);
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;
var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

Any thoughts on this problem?  I'd love to just launch the external application directly instead of using a proxy, as that will keep complexity down between deployment platforms.

Comment: Not a solution, but a mitigation: hide the AIR app?

Answer (score 0):

What about minimizing the application?

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.minimize();
```